# Android Bitmap.getPixel() Is Annoyingly Inaccuracte

Tags: android, bitmap, getpixel

Project OverView : Theres two images. Click the top image (in my app i use a cat pic) and it will set the bottom image background to the color of the pixel on the location you clicked at.

The Problem: The background color doesn't match the color of the pixel at the location of your click at times its randomly colored, other times its off by a few shades. Its wierd.

**This is the main java code :**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class ColorRead extends Activity 
implements OnTouchListener{
 Integer myColor;
 String TAG;
 Bitmap bMap,bMap2;
 ImageView image,image2;
 Button BTN;
 MotionEvent mEvent;
 Integer touchX,touchY;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle Icicle) {
        super.onCreate(Icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.catpic);
        image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bitmap2);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bitmap);
        image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
        image.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
    public void scanForColor(int xMouse, int yMouse)
    {
     myColor = bMap.getPixel(xMouse,yMouse);
     Log.i(TAG, " R:"+Color.red(myColor)+" G:"+Color.green(myColor)+" B:"+Color.blue(myColor));
     image2.setBackgroundColor(myColor);
    }

 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
  Integer id = v.getId();
  switch(id)
  {
  case R.id.bitmap:
   if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
         {
                 touchX = (int)e.getX();
                 touchY = (int)e.getY();
         }
   scanForColor(touchX,touchY);
         Log.i(TAG,touchX.toString());
         break;
    default:
     break;
  }
        return false;
 }
}
```

**Heres the Main.XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/bitmap"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/catpic"
    />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/bitmap2"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/catpic"
    />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/myButton"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What makes you think that a human finger is capable of accurately tapping on a specific pixel on a touchscreen?

Comment: I had the click of the mouse used, of course i typecasted from a float to an int losing data but after i woke up from my drunken stoopor(sp.) from last night's party i just realized that It was because i scaled the image perhaps and the bitmap getpixel coordinates werent scaled to the screen im going to test this ill report back to stackedoverflow if it worked or not FURHTRMEORE if u want we c an teamview and code this because im going to be making facial recognitiion software for the phone.